# Node and mongoose - Acces object inside another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I got this schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var userSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({

    email: {type:String, unique: true, lowercase: true},

    cpf: String,

    password: String,

    profile:{
        name:{type:String, default:''},
        photo: {type:String, default:''}
    },

    adress:String,

    history:[{
        date: Date,
        paid:{type:Number, default:0},
        item:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Products'}
    }]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

But, when I use User.create({email:req.body.email, password:req.body.password, profile.name: req.body.name}), when I try to pass some value to profile.name, console gives me an error. SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

How can I acess this object and pass some value for him?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript lets you omit the quotes around keys on objects if your key contains a limited set of characters. The period `.` isn't one of them so you need to quote your key.

```
User.create({
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password,
  'profile.name': req.body.name
})
```

Comment: Thanks, my dear friend.

Comment: But, if I try to use it on a EJS file, will work? like: <%= result.profile.name %>

Comment: Yes. Then you're accessing the data (in this case, the person's name). That's like storing the values on the right side of the code.